# Append HTML to XOM element

Tags: java, xml, xom

I need to prepend HTML to existed XOM element. HTML represented as a String.

Here are my actions

1. Parse String into XOM Document
2. Remove root element(**X**) from Document
3. Prepend X to desired target element (**Y**)

I get an exception

```
nu.xom.WellformednessException: Cannot remove the root element
    at nu.xom.Document.removeChild(Unknown Source)
    at nu.xom.Node.detach(Unknown Source)
```

---

X element HTML

```
<div>
  Some test text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Current XOM implementation does **not allow to remove root node**.

To achieve desired goal it is need to **add fake** root and then detach required node.

In a context of mentioned step set:

Replace step 2 with next

1. Add fake root element  - `document.setRootElement(new Element("div"))`
2. Detach desired element - `element.detach()`